# Browser plugins auto update flow?

Tags: npapi, auto-update

I'm curious for all you browser plugin (NPAPI & ActiveX) developers out there what methods you've used for automatically updating your plugins (on both Windows and OSX platforms)?

My end goal would be to make the installation of the plugin as simple as possible (ie, not require the user to install additional software needed to auto-update - so it'd have to be someone integrated with the plugin itself, or at least for Windows anyway, I can probably get away from that on OSX).

Any thoughts or tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is the update procedure I use for 3 browsers: IE, Chrome and Firefox

**Internet Explorer**

Inside your `<object codebase="" ... />` element, you can append the version to your cab filename. The new cab will be automatically downloaded if necessary.

Example : `<object codebase="myPlugin.cab#Version=X,Y,Z" ... />`

This is suitable if the plugin is used on a single webpage. If your plugin is meant to be distributed accross multiple websites, store the latest version string on the server hosting your plugin and every website can ask for it on loading and update the codebase.

**FireFox**

I am not going to explain the full Firefox update process here, but basically, there are two files : `install.rdf` and `update.rdf`.

The first one is embedded into the plugin package and contains a URL to the update.rdf file. When the plugin package is updated, just update the update.rdf file and firefox (if correctly configured) will check automatically this file and download then install the new one.

**Chrome**

Very close to Firefox, your plugin must link to an xml file that points to the lastest plugin.